# Who is Lord Shiva in religion that grew out of Hinduism?

Tags: shiva

As Buddhism grew, a number of Hindu deities were incorporated into Buddhism. For example, Saraswati became Benzaiten in Japan. Did this happen with Lord Shiva? If so, what name is he called in Asian cultures outside of India?

Comment: Read here- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrathful_deities

Comment: If your question is about Buddhism, try [Buddhism.stackexchange.com](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In Buddhism, Lord Shiva is Hevajra. Read here- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hevajra

Comment: @Aghori Are you sure Hevajra is shiva? If yes, gather some more sources and post it as an answer. Answering is much better than commenting.

Comment: @Aghori ... I'm not seeing anything in Tibetan Buddhism that clearly identifies Hevajra or other wrathful deities with Shiva. Could you post more specific as an answer?